# Chain execution of array of promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to create a chain of promises where each promise waits for the previous promise before getting executed.

```js
const syncStatusChanges = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("in")

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("done")
            resolve({ done: true })
        }, 2000);
    });
}


const run = () => {
  const promises = [syncStatusChanges(), syncStatusChanges()]
  promises[0].then(res => {
      console.log("done 1")
      promises[1].then(res => {
          console.log("done 2")
      })
  })
}

run()
```

In this example the output is:

```
in
in
done
done 1
done
done 2
```

But I want it to be:

```
in
done
done 1
in
done
done 2
```

I also want it to work for any n number of functions. I saw this answer but the output is the same!

```
var promise = statusChangeCalls[0];
for (var i = 1; i < statusChangeCalls.length; i++)
    promise = promise.then(statusChangeCalls[i]);
```

Comment: You already executed your functions when creating the `promise` array. Use just function references there and execute later.

Comment: You *execute* the promises together, so they won't wait for each other.

Comment: Oh @Sirko I see what you mean. But what if I need to pass parameter in it?

Comment: Cus I push the functions into an array, ```promises.push(someFunc(param))```

Comment: If you need parameters, you could use `bind()` to add them beforehand.

Comment: You can push the promises but the work is *already being done*. A Promise means that you *will* get a value later, there is something already running not something you can delay.

Comment: @Sirko I cant seem to figure out the binding, I tried ```promises.push(someFunc.bing(param))``` but when the function runs the param is `undefined`

Comment: @beckas the first argument to `.bind` is the *context* that the function would use. The second  argument onwards would be forwarded as argument of the function. So, you can just do `fn.bind(null, param)` - you don't care about the context, so `null` is fine. If your function takes multiple parameters, then `fn.bind(null, param1, param2, param3)` etc. If your function takes two parameters but you only pass one, then you still need to supply the second one when you execute it `newFn = fn.bind(null, param1); newFn(param2)`

Comment: @VLAZ what a champ! thanks brother

Answer (score 0):

As it is written in comments. You are executing the functions in the array itself. What i understood by seeing your output. below run function can help you.

```
  const run = () => {
  const promise = syncStatusChanges();
  promise.then(res => {
     console.log("done 1")
     syncStatusChanges().then(res => {
         console.log("done 2")
     })
  })
}
```

Promise executes eagerly. It does not wait to register the then function. You can look for [observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html), they are lazy in execution. Basically they wait until you subscribe them.

For your second doubt about loop. You can use **async** **await** keyword to achieve chaining. Just pass number as an parameter in runInLoop function to execute promise that many times.

```
const runInLoop = async(numberOfPromisesCall)=> {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPromisesCall; i++){
       await syncStatusChanges();
       console.log(`done ${i + 1}`);
  }
} 
runInLoop(5)
```